# Offline Polymer Documentation

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-designer-tool

I am really confused with how to get and run the Polymer Documentation Offline since I am using Windows. I am not an expert with cmd and I always get errors.

Here's the error:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you post what you have tried and what errors you get?

Comment: I'll try later :) well I am hoping for a folder that has the index file I have to run on a server.